# Azure Event Grid - Configure client certificates for Hybrid connection

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

can anyone please tell how to add client certificate to Hybrid Connection or point me to the document that explains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Hybrid Connections only support [SAS-based Authentication and Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-authentication-and-authorization).